Custom labels not working in LWC for managed packages
I create managed packages of the first and second generations. Some LWC require translations and I use Custom Labels to achieve that:
import myLabel from "@salesforce/label/c.myLabel";
And it all works fine in my dev environment, the translations are properly retrieved and displayed when switching user language.
However when I add that to a managed package (either first or second generation), only the default English wording is shown when I switch languages in an org with that package installed. And therefore I need to use some apex walkaround to retrieve certain labels and pass them to LWC wherever necessary and this approach always works without any problems.
I did check the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-labels.html
which states:
import labelName from "@salesforce/label/labelReference";
labelName—A name that refers to the label.
labelReference—The name of the label in your org in the format namespace.labelName. We use this format because it’s the same format used in managed packages, in Visualforce, and in other Salesforce technologies. You can use the same format to access labels, myns.labelName, regardless of where you’re accessing them.

I also tried
import myLabel from "@salesforce/label/mynamespace.myLabel"; but this doesn't get deployed in neither org with a registered namespace nor in an org without any namespace. It just throws a deployment error:
Invalid module id "mynamespace.Record_Type_Label" for type "label". Explicit use of namespace "mynamespace" in file "myLwcFile.js" is prohibited. Use default namespace "c" instead.
So the question is: why don't Custom Labels display proper translations in my manage package?
It all works fine in my dev orgs and I definitely added translations as well as Custom Labels to the package itself. If I use apex to get the labels and pass them to LWC - it all works fine in every environment.
